# Does node.js support setting session with mutliple asynchronous HTTP calls?

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

In my node.js app , I'm setting the session using async calls. I have used [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for the session management. **But setting the session behaves occasionally**. I'm calling the 2 node.js routes using an angular app.

First time it will call the HTTP get calls and get all the data correctly. But only the last delayed route data will be set to the session. Not data from both route. Seems like setting the data from the delayed route is replacing the fast route session data. Here's my code.

Sometimes all the data is set to the session. (After 2 browser refreshes)

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // the session is stored in a cookie, so we use this to parse it

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/'));
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: '232332dfdffd',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 }}))

app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

var server = app.listen(8081,function(){
});


app.get('/route1', function(req, res , next) {   

var data1 = req.session.data1;

    if(data1){
        console.log("Session is not null. Getting data1 from session");
        res.status(200);
        res.send(data1);
    }else{    

        request({
            url: "testUrl",
            qs: {},
            json: req.body,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }, function(error, response, body){

            if(error) {
                console.log("error "+error);
                res.sendStatus(error);
            } else {
                req.session.data1 = response;
                res.status(response.statusCode);
                res.send(response);
            }
        });
    }


});


app.get('/route2', function(req, res , next) {   

var data2 = req.session.data2;

    if(data2){
        console.log("Session is not null. Getting data2 from session");
        res.status(200);
        res.send(data1);
    }else{    

        request({
            url: "testUrl2",
            qs: {},
            json: req.body,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }, function(error, response, body){

            if(error) {
                console.log("error "+error);
                res.sendStatus(error);
            } else {
                req.session.data2 = response;
                res.status(response.statusCode);
                res.send(response);
            }
        });
    }


});
```